# How to avoid using tuples and what will this look like without list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm supposed to program in Python, and I've only used Python for 3 weeks. I have  to solve all kinds of problems and write functions as training. For one of my functions I use this line.

```
theDict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

However I can't use anything I don't fully understand or can't fully explain. I understand the gist of the line, but, I can't really explain it. So my instructor told me that to use this, i must learn ether everything about tuples and fully understand list comprehension, or i must write that in pure python.

The line basically looks into a dictionary, and inside the dictionary, its supposed to look for values that are equal to empty lists and delete those keys/values.

So, my question is, what would this line look like in pure, non list comprehension python?
I'll attempt to write it because I want to try my best, and this isn't a website where you get  free answers, but you guys correct me and help me finish it if it doesn't work.

Also another problem is that, the empty lists inside the 'value' of the dictionary, if they are empty, then they won't be processed inside the loop. The loop is supposed  to  delete the key that is equal to the empty value. So how are you supposed to check if the list is empty, if the check is inside the loop, and the loop won't have the empty array in its body?

```
for key,value in TheDict.items(): #i need to add 'if value:' somewhere, 
#but i don't know how to add it to make it work, because 
#this checks if the value exists or not, but if the value 
#doesn't exist, then it won't go though this area, so 
#there is no way to see if the value exists or not. 
     theDict[key]=value
```

If there is a better method to remove dictionary values that have a value of an empty list. please let me know.

And how will

```
theDict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

look like if it didn't use a generator?

Comment: you aren't using a generator btw, although you should be, just remove the `[`,`]` so it's `dict((k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0)`

Comment: @jamylak well when i removed the brackets  and used the type() function what was left. it said that it was generator. type( (k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0)  this returns generator

Comment: "this checks if the value exists or not" - actually, `if value:` is the same as `if value == '':`, so it checks if `value` is an empty (but existent) string stored in the dictionary.

Comment: @WebMaster Yes exactly but with the square brackets it's a list comprehension.

Comment: @WebMaster, The `dict` constructor knows how to consume a generator expression. The result will be the same as with the LC, but not using so much temporary memory

Comment: This _is_ pure Python. Your instructor doesn't know what he's talking about

Comment: You should accept the answers which have been helpful to you so far, in order to get more help from other users...

Comment: 1. Why do you have "an instructor" in a job scenario? 2. If you have to get help on the internet with this sort of thing in order to keep a job, I have zero sympathy for you; the company is paying real money for someone who can do this sort of thing themselves.

Comment: because i'm supposed to go though testing before i get the job, i passed all the tests, but i have to explain what i have done and how, and if i can't fully understand, or fully explain, i have to use something else. Yes i know its pure python, it's my fault for bad  phrasing. i just need something simpler then that. like the for k,v loop that someone has posted here. but the value == [] check has to be somewhere outside the loop, it has to be before the loop. I don't know how to do this but i do know that since the value is simply [], it doesn't go inside the loop.itis ignored by the for loop

Comment: and they are not paying me real money, i'm a ****ing intern, that means they will pay me minimum wage. I signed up for PHP, but they put me on python, didn't even let me choose, just said, do python. These little problems and functions, are way harder then the actual job will ever be. so i've been doing this for THREE WEEKS, without pay. it's ridiculous, almost a month, of free labor, most people i know wouldn't dream of even coming close to doing what i've been doing for 3 weeks. full8 hour shifts + homework. and you don't even have sympathy for me? I just graduated from high school.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel how am i, free intern, graduated from high school, am supposed to solve these problems, that professional programmers from stack-overflow have trouble with?

Comment: *but they put me on python, didn't even let me choose, just said, do python* - Sounds like good advice

Comment: wanna help? how do i use the bounty function of this website?

Comment: Questions must be 2 days old before you can add a bounty.

Comment: @WebMaster: you asked three or four questions about that bloody function and although some good solutions were suggested to you, you don't seem to have learned anything from them (looking at your auto-answer here). Good luck with your job, but if you were _my_ intern, you wouldn't stay longer than a minute - not because you don't know something, but because you're obviously unwilling or unable to learn.

Comment: @thg435 that's probably because the problem wasn't in the process of deleting the 'bloody' element. I don't know what the problem is anymore. When i got the solution and used it with my old program. the output wasn't what i wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result = dict([(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

will look like(if you want new dictionary)

```
result = {}
for key, value in theDict.items():
    if len(value) > 0:
        result[key] = value
```

if you want to modify existing dictionary:

```
for key, value in theDict.items():
    if not len(value) > 0:
        del theDict[key]
```

Comment: There is a problem! since the VALUE is EQUAL to an empty list. the program will not loop THOUGH an empty list. so the if value: WILL NEVER be triggered.

Comment: No, the line `for key, value in theDict.items():` doesn't care if the strings stored in the dictionary are empty or not.

Comment: you should use `if len(value)>0:` to guarantee the same behaviour

Comment: @gnibbler: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean

Comment: Simple not very good example - Suppose there is a value of `None`. This would cause an exception, but in your code it will be silently ignored

Comment: @WebMaster And what's wrong with this one? Apart from the goop you posted above, which frankly makes less sense than the original post. Here I'm implying that the original post was very light on sense to begin with.

Comment: LOOK, for and the in, go through the dictionary, iterating over all the values, correct? or whatever. IF THE VALUE IS equal to [] or an empty list. then it doesn't iterate through that specific list. so the part of the program that checks whether or not the list is empty, is never used on the empty value because it never iterates, so the loop body doesn't apply to that specific dictionary value that has an empty list in it

Comment: @WebMaster, It's not iterating through the list. It's only iterating through the dictionary. An empty list is a value. So if a dictionary element has an empty list as value, your loop will run with `key` set to the key of the entry, and `value` set to [].

Comment: wow, i created a question that was deleted, but it had so many downvotes before it was deleted that it banned me from asking questions. how do i use bounty?

Comment: @matt where it says the dictionary size changed, use items() instead of iteritems.

Comment: @matt none of the examples work, i have tested this, and confirmed it, and other people confirmed this problem, just no one has the solution unless you use that single line. the problem is that when iterating over the dictionary, when the value is equal to an empty list, it ignores that specific value and doesn't put it though the loop

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Python just doesn't work that way - it will not ignore an entry in the dictionary just because the value is `[]`.

Comment: Hey, i have edited the post, now you can try the code for yourself

Comment: @WebMaster Please do. I have tested the examples in this answer and they do work for me.

Comment: @WebMaster What output do you expect from `print CleanWhitespace(...)`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12552/discussion-between-matt-and-web-master)

Comment: this is what im getting {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': ['c', ' '], 'd': []}
this is what i want {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': ['c', ' ']}

Answer (score 4):

`if v` signifies if `v` has some value, if `v` donesn't have any value, control will not enter the condition and skip the value

```
In [25]: theDict={'1':'2','3':'', '4':[]}

In [26]: for k,v in theDict.items():
   ....:     if v:
   ....:         newDict[k]=v
   ....:

In [27]: newDict
Out[27]: {'1': '2'}
```

==========================

```
In [2]: theDict = { 1: ['e', 'f'], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['d', ' '], 5: [] }

In [3]: newDict = {}

In [4]: for k,v in theDict.items():
   ...:     if v:
   ...:         newDict[k]=v
   ...:

In [5]: newDict
Out[5]: {1: ['e', 'f'], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['d', ' ']}
```

Updated the answer as per your input...

Comment: does it work with     {
        1: ['e', 'f'],             
        2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],        
        4: ['d', ' '],
 5: []
    }

Comment: This specific function is only supposed to remove keys that have the value of '[]' For example KEY 5 has the VALUE of '[]' so key 5:[] must be delete and everything else must be returned in the same except way except with the key 5 missing. THANK YOU. sorry for slow reply, thank you again, i really hope your still online

Comment: It did not work {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': ['c', ' '], 'd': []}
the [] never actually goes to the for k,v loop. because its empty, there is nothing to go to the loop. the if v: is never executed with the d key using the dict {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': ['c', ' '], 'd': []}

Answer (score 3):

To remove an element from a dictionary, you can use the `del` keyword:

```
>>> d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> d
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> del d[1]
>>> d
{3: 4}
>>>
```

This will probably be more efficient than generating a completely new dictionary. Then, you can use a similar structure to above:

```
for k in theDict:
    if len(theDict[k]) == 0:
        del theDict[k]
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work. since value is blank, it never iterates over any kind of loop. this only works with my list comprehension example that i can't  use

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
from operator import itemgetter
theDict = dict(filter(itemgetter(1), theDict.items()))
```

Comment: @WebMaster, maybe your instructor can explain it to you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
theDict = dict( [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v)>0])
```

*However I can't use anything I don't fully understand or can't fully explain. I understand the gist of the line, but, I can't really explain it.*

---

**Background**

The easiest way to understand or demo behaviour in python is using the interactive interpreter:
 `python -i`

In the interactive interpreter there are two fabulously useful commands:

- `dir` - takes an optional argument of an object, returns a list of the attributes on the object.
- `help` - accesses inline documentation

You can use `dir` to find out, for example what methods an object has and then look at their documentation using `help`.

---

**Explaining the line in question**

Here's a sample dictionary:

```
>>> theDict = dict(a=[1,2],b=[3,4],c=[])
>>> theDict
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

The [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) returns a list of key-value pairs as tuples:

```
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items()]
[('a', [1, 2]), ('c', []), ('b', [3, 4])]
```

The `if` statement filters the resulting list.

```
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v) > 0]
[('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [3, 4])]
```

The [dict](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) can be instantiated with a sequence of key-value pairs:

```
>>> dict([(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v) > 0])
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Putting it all together:

```
>>> theDict = dict(a=[1,2],b=[3,4],c=[])
>>> theDict
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [], 'b': [3, 4]}
>>> theDict = dict([(k,v) for k,v in theDict.items() if len(v) > 0])
>>> theDict
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

The original dict object is replaced with a new one instantiated using the list comprehension filtered list of it's key-value pairs.

If you follow all this (and play with it yourself in the interactive interpreter) you will understand what's going on in this line of code you've asked about.

Comment: Thank you, ill take my time to read this thoroughly. i updated my overall program in the post, still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list` as the empty value.

Comment: what do you mean? and i need to delete the lists with empty value along with the key that is with it

Answer (score 1):

Here's your function in a more or less readable way:

```
def clean_whitespace(dct):
    out = {}
    for key, val in dct.items():
        val = map(str.strip, val)
        val = filter(None, val)
        if val:
            out[key] = val
    return out
```

or, using comprehensions,

```
def clean_whitespace(dct):
    out = {}
    for key, val in dct.items():
        val = [x.strip() for x in val]
        val = [x for x in val if x]
        if val:
            out[key] = val
    return out
```

Let us know if you need comments or explanations.

Comment: i reposted my new function, still doesn't work, but ill take my time to go though this post here.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was under my nose. sorry guys. thank you for all your help +1 for everyone

```
def CleanWhiteSpace(theDict) :
    for k,v in theDict.items():
        if not v:
            del theDict[k]
    return theDict
```